# Button share bad url

Tags: java, android

i have problem when try share mp3 file from res/raw device throws an error "Invalid path"

My code:

```
    Uri rawUri = getRawUri("sound1.mp3");
    btn_shareaudio = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

    btn_shareaudio.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    final Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    shareIntent.setType("audio/*");
                    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, rawUri);
                    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Condividi attraverso:"));
                }
            });

public Uri getRawUri(String filename) {
        return Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE + File.pathSeparator + File.separator + getPackageName() + "/raw/" + filename);
    }
```